# Autowire Bean with constructor parameters

Tags: java, spring

I've got a bean with constructor parameters which I want to autowire into another bean using annotations. If I define the bean in the main config and pass in the constructor parameters there then it works fine. However, I have no main config but use `@Component` along with `@ComponentScan` to register the beans. I've tried using `@Value` property to define the parameters but then I get the exception  **No default constructor found;**

```
@Component
public class Bean {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    
    public Bean(@Value("a") String a, @Value("b") String b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("printing");
    }
    
}


@Component
public class SecondBean {

    private Bean bean;
    
    @Autowired
    public SecondBean(Bean bean)
    {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
    
    public void callPrint()
    {
        bean.print();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor for `Bean` needs to be annotated with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`, otherwise Spring will try to construct it using the default constructor and you don't have one of those.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) for `@Autowired` says that it is used to mark a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities. In this case you need to tell Spring that the appropriate constructor to use for autowiring the dependency is not the default constructor. In this case you're asking Spring to create `SecondBean` instance, and to do that it needs to create a `Bean` instance. In the absence of an annotated constructor, Spring will attempt to use a default constructor.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: thanks..I just don't understand why I need to put Autowired on the Bean as well..I am not injecting a bean into the Bean class. Usually one uses Autowired or @Inject for DI..do you have any doc reference?